# How to prove KL(q(z)|p(z)) = E_q(z) [ log f(z) ] where f is the CDF of p?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, kullback-leibler

As title. It was used in https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.10549 without proving.

[image]

Comment: You may find it useful to use math formatting. More information https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I couldn't verify the results for p,q exponential with different parameters, if I'm not mistaken.